# index out of range error while iterating the list items

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, indexoutofrangeexception

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=requests.get('https://www.foxsports.com/golf/golfers?association=1&teamId=0&season=2019&position=0&page=1’)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser’)
player_name_list = soup.find(class_= 'wisbb_players’)
player_name_list_items = player_name_list.findAll('a’)
for player_name in player_name_list_items:
    names = player_name.contents[1]
    print(names.text)
```

I can't use 0 in contents. It prints out a couple of numbers at the bottom of the screen after printing out a long white space, which I am thinking is where the list of names is supposed to be.

On this web site there are 2 span tags for every name. I have been trying to get it to only print one name for quite a while, and when I finally did get it to, it gave me an error. I don't know what else to say. I have been trying to post this for about 30 minutes. If something in this post is wrong, let me know. I am just trying to get my question up here.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because the last four elements from `player_name_list_items` are not player names. So if you check `player_name.contents` you'll get only `['2']`, because this list has one element, when it tries to do  `player_name.contents[1]` you'll get an out of range error. To bypass that you can use an `if` statement:

Try this:

```
for player_name in player_name_list_items:
    if player_name.span:
        print(player_name.span.text)
    else:
        print('Not a name')
```

Output:

```
Adamonis, Brad
Adams, Frank
Albertson, Anders
Allan, Stephen
Allenby, James
Allenby, Robert
Alverio, Max
An, Byeong Hun
Ancer, Abraham
Anderson, Mark
Anderson, Matthew
Anguiano, Mark
Aphibarnrat, Kiradech
Appleby, Stuart
Arendell, Connor
Armour, Ryan
Armstrong, Dawson
Arnaus, Adri
Asaji, Yosuke
Ashun, Wu
Atwal, Arjun
Augenstein, John
Axley, Eric
Baddeley, Aaron
Bae, Sang-Moon
Not a name
Not a name
Not a name
Not a name
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your selector to only retrieve first child span i.e. first player name occurence

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.foxsports.com/golf/golfers?association=1&teamId=0&season=2019&position=0&page=1')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
#bs4 4.7.1 +
players = [i.text for i in soup.select('.wisbb_fullPlayer > span:first-child')]
#or < 4.7.1
players = [i.text for i in soup.select('.wisbb_fullPlayer > span:nth-of-type(1)')]
print(players)
```

Comment: this gives me this NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ffd60b80a73e> in <module>
----> 1 players = [i.text for i in soup.select('.wisbb_fullPlayer > span:first-child')]
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: requires bs4 4.7.1 + . It is worth upgrading as it supports for features and I believe is more accurate.

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade use: players = [i.text for i in soup.select('.wisbb_fullPlayer > span:nth-of-type(1)')]